# Python loop json data then output json without separator

Tags: python, json

i'm newbie with python and try to create a python script that can loop in my json data then output the result into new json file.
but the json.dumps(output) is without a comma separator which is not a valid json, any help are welcome.

here is my json data:

```
{
"product1":[
  {"date":"10-6-2022", "title":"adidas", "qty":"250", "origin":"vietnam"},
  {"date":"10-7-2022", "title":"nike", "qty":"200", "origin":"new zeland"},
  {"date":"10-8-2022", "title":"puma", "qty":"180", "origin":"USA"}
],
"product2":[
  {"date":"10-6-2022", "title":"ecco", "qty":"120", "origin":"france"},
  {"date":"10-7-2022", "title":"under armor", "qty":"450", "origin":"china"},
  {"date":"10-8-2022", "title":"fila", "qty":"360", "origin":"turkey"}
]
```

}

here is my python script:

```
import json
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
dty = today.strftime("%#m-%#d-%Y")

f = open('2.json')
data = json.loads(f.read())

for k, v in data.items():
  for x in range(3):
 title = v[x]['title']
 quantity = v[x]['qty']
 origin = v[x]['origin']
 
 if v[x]['date'] == dty:
     products = {
         "title": title,
         "quantity" : quantity,
         "origin" : origin,
         "date" : dty
     }
     print(products)
```

The output is like that :

```
{'title': 'adidas', 'quantity': '250', 'origin': 'vietnam', 'date': '10-6-2022'}
{'title': 'ecco', 'quantity': '120', 'origin': 'france', 'date': '10-6-2022'}
```

But i want to have a comma separator data like that:

```
{'title': 'adidas', 'quantity': '250', 'origin': 'vietnam', 'date': '10-6-2022'},
{'title': 'ecco', 'quantity': '120', 'origin': 'france', 'date': '10-6-2022'}
```

even i json.dumps the result, it's the same

```
     stock = json.dumps(products, indent=2)
     print(stock)
```

I got this :

```
{
"title": "adidas",  
"quantity": "250",  
"origin": "vietnam",
"date": "10-6-2022" 
}
{
"title": "ecco",
"quantity": "120",
"origin": "france",
"date": "10-6-2022"
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are not using `json.dumps()`. You should collect your items into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list and in that code you aren't using json.dumps()

Try this:

```
import json
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
dty = today.strftime("%#m-%#d-%Y")

f = open('2.json')
data = json.loads(f.read())
product_list = []
for k, v in data.items():
  for x in range(3):
      title = v[x]['title']
      quantity = v[x]['qty']
      origin = v[x]['origin']
 
      if v[x]['date'] == dty:
         products = {
         "title": title,
         "quantity" : quantity,
         "origin" : origin,
         "date" : dty
         }
         product_list.append(products)
 print(json.dumps(products))
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your help, it works like a charm. my mistake was to try this inside the second for loop.

Comment: Yes, but you need to use a python list (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)